# Why isn't my home.js displaying anything in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am enrolled in a full stack web development course and currently learning react on the side to build a project for a portfolio in hopes of getting into a front end web developer position.

Found this 2 year old tutorial in which I thought was a decent start to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwarZBtFoFA&t=700s.

I've tried and noticed the following:

1. The HTML doesn't show up in the browser inspect
2. locahost:3000 (nothing)
3. localhost:3000/Home (nothing)
4. I've followed the tutorial (rewatching if i missed any steps)
5. compared my code to the tutorials' repository code
6. started from scratch twice (for Home.js/App.js)
7. changed  to <Route path="/" exact component={} />
8. the only thing I'm getting the following error on browser (nothing on VSC):

**Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot**

AND

**No routes matched location "/Home"**

I've updated and checked the version for react and says 10.2.4, haven't been able to find out whether it's version React 18 or less. How do I implement the createRoot to the existing documents I have?

T.I.A

**pages/Home.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <div className='headerContainer'>
                <h1>Heavy Hitters Gym</h1>
                <p>WHERE YOU GET FIT</p>
                <Link to="/Menu">
                    <button> JOIN NOW </button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**src/App.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/index.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: _"How do I implement the createRoot"_... did you try visiting the link provided in the warning message?

Comment: Honestly, given you are in a course figuring this out, I'd suggest finding a different tutorial that is **not** 2 years old

Comment: As a professional react developer I highly suggest you do NOT learn through that tutorial. React has had a lot of IMPORTANT upgrades and changes in the past few years, especially with routes and security. Because of this, any tutorial before 18 will not be very useful, even small things such as how all old tutorials start such as create-react-app are no longer supported and if you take those old skills to a react developer interview, you will not bode well

Answer (score -2):

About the first error message, React is complaining about you using ReactDOM.render() in the index.ts file and is asking you to use ReactDOM.createRoot(), because the ReactDOM.render() is outdated.

In the **src/index.js** file replace to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

About the second error message, the "/Home" path really does not exist in your code, so this error is expected when you try to access this path.

The real problem is that inside the file **src/App.js** you are passing `Home` in the "component" prop

```
...
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
...
```

But the "component" prop actually expects the whole JSX Element. So you can fix it by replacing the code to this:

```
...
<Route path="/" exact component={<Home/>} />
...
```